# Trim last + from string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to generate a link using jQuery and need to trim the last '+' sign off the end. Is there a way to detect if there is one there, and then trim it off?

So far the code removes the word 'hotel' and replaces spaces with '+', I think I just need another replace for the '+' that shows up sometimes but not sure how to be super specific with it.

```
var nameSearch = name.replace("Hotel", "");
nameSearch = nameSearch.replace(/ /g, "+");
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `var nameSearch = name.replace("Hotel", "").replace(/ /g, "+").replace(/\+$/, '')`

Comment: @anubhava thanks, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `String.prototype.trim()` before you call replace, in order to remove the leading and trailing white-space from the String:

```
var nameSearch = name.trim().replace("Hotel", "").replace(/ /g, "+");
```

References:

- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score 1):

You can target the end of the string within a Regex with the `$` character. You can remove the `+` signs from the end like this.

```
nameSearch = nameSearch.replace(/\+*$/g, "");
```

But even better, as [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40808228/1323504) pointed out, you should call `trim` on the string before your manipulation, so it won't have any leading and trailing white-spaces, hence you won't need to trim the `+` signs.